# Get union and intersection of jsonb array in Postgresql

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, union, jsonb

I have a DB of people with jsonb column `interests`. In my application user can search for people by providing their hobbies which is set of some predefined values. I want to offer him a best match and in order to do so I would like to count match as intersection/union of interests. This way the top results won't be people who have plenty of hobbies in my DB.
Example:

DB records:

```
name    interests::jsonb
Mary    ["swimming","reading","jogging"]
John    ["climbing","reading"]
Ann     ["swimming","watching TV","programming"]
Carl    ["knitting"]
```

user input in app:

```
["reading", "swimming", "knitting", "cars"]
```

my script should output this:

```
Mary    0.4
John    0.2
Ann     0.16667
Carl    0.25
```

Now I'm using

```
SELECT name 
  FROM people 
 WHERE interests @> 
   ANY (ARRAY ['"reading"', '"swimming"', '"knitting"', '"cars"']::jsonb[])
```

but this gives me even records with many interests and no way to order it.
Is there any way I can achieve it in a reasonable time - let's say up to 5 seconds in DB with around 400K records?

**EDIT**:
I added another example to clarify my calculations. My calculation needs to filter people with many hobbies. Therefore match should be calculated as Intersection(input, db_record)/Union(input, db_record).

Example:
input = `["reading"]`

DB records:

```
name    interests::jsonb
Mary    ["swimming","reading","jogging"]
John    ["climbing","reading"]
Ann     ["swimming","watching TV","programming"]
Carl    ["reading"]
```

Match for Mary would be calculated as `(LENGTH(["reading"]))/(LENGTH(["swimming","reading","jogging"]))` which is 0.3333
and for Carl it would be `(LENGTH(["reading"]))/LENGTH([("reading")])` which is 1

**UPDATE**: I managed to do it with

```
SELECT result.id, result.name, result.overlap_count/(jsonb_array_length(persons.interests) + 4 - result.overlap_count)::decimal as score 
FROM (SELECT t1.name as name, t1.id, COUNT(t1.name) as overlap_count
      FROM (SELECT name, id, jsonb_array_elements(interests)
            FROM persons) as t1
      JOIN (SELECT unnest(ARRAY ['"reading"', '"swimming"', '"knitting"', '"cars"'])::jsonb as elements) as t2 ON t1.jsonb_array_elements = t2.elements 
      GROUP BY t1.name, t1.id) as result 
JOIN persons ON result.id = persons.id ORDER BY score desc
```

Here's my fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b4b1760854b2d77a1c7e6011d074a1a3

However it's not fast enough and I would appreciate any improvements.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to unnest the parameter and use the `?` operator to check each and every element the `jsonb` array:

```
select
    t.name,
    x.match_ratio
from mytable t
cross join lateral (
    select avg( (t.interests ? a.val)::int ) match_ratio
    from unnest(array['reading', 'swimming', 'knitting', 'cars']) a(val)
) x
```

It is not very clear what are the rules behind the result that you are showing. This gives you a ratio that represents the percentage of values in the parameter array that can be found in the `interests` of each person (so Mary gets 0.5 since she has two interests in common with the search parameter, and all other names get 0.25).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5b11fcd3267823236b83ba28aaa41099)**

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `jsonb_array_elements()` to unnest the jsonb column :

```
SELECT name, count / SUM(count) over () AS ratio
  FROM(
       SELECT name, COUNT(name) AS count
         FROM people 
         JOIN jsonb_array_elements(interests) AS j(elm) ON TRUE
        WHERE interests @> 
          ANY (ARRAY ['"reading"', '"swimming"', '"knitting"', '"cars"']::jsonb[])
        GROUP BY name ) q
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=14c4e6faf218c61166be36fb63cb602a)</kbd>